# Cannot change permissions as root on a file owned by root

Tags: permissions, selinux, ownership

The problem is that I have PHP files that do not work in the browser. I suspect because the user is missing `read` permissions.

The files are located in a dir called "ajax"

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 4096 Sep 13 14:33 ajax
```

The content of that dir:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13199 Sep 13 14:33 getOrderDeliveryDates.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20580 Sep 13 14:33 getParcelShops.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  1218 Sep 13 14:33 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   814 Sep 13 14:33 lang.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  6001 Sep 13 14:33 prod_reviews.php
```

I'm 100% certain logged in as root:

```
[root@accept: nl (MP-git-branch)] $
```

doublecheck with command `id`:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

It is driving me nuts.

tried sudo (even though I already am root).

```
sudo chmod 777 filename
```

tried chown (even though I already am the owner root).

```
 sudo root filename
```

There are no errors or warnings at all.

OS is CentOS 6

Comment: From the looks of your id command, you have selinux running. This is probably why you cannot make amendments.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Can you explain why and/or how to solve this?

Comment: Is the file located on a non-Unix filesystem (like a shared Windows partition)?

Comment: A quick fix is disable selinux with "setenforce 0" and then re-run the command before re-enabling with setenforce 1. If you are looking to modify a number of files, you would be better served interrogating your audit files in /etc/audit/audit.log and updating selinux contexts with audit2allow

Comment: Please add to your question  the output of running this command in the affected directory - `mount | grep -F "$( df -h . | sed '2s/^.*%//' ) "`

Comment: What is the permission of directories leading to `ajax`?

Comment: @Kusalananda It **was** a vagrant box (origin unknown) but after some time we no longer needed the vagrant/rsync part and we turned in a regular VM running inside windows server.

Comment: @roaima CentOS 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS (and other Fedora/RHEL derivatives) enables an additional security mechanism known as SELinux. It applies additional restrictions on most system daemons. These additional restrictions are checked after regular unix permissions.

For non-default configurations you often need to adjust SELinux. Files contain a specific security label, which is used by SELinux to apply the security policy. If your problem only occurs with some files, you need to correct the SELinux labels on the problematic files. Use [`chcon`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) with `--reference=` option to copy the label from a file which works to apply the same label on your problematic file(s):

```
chcon --reference=<path to working file> <path to not working file(s)>
```

If your files are in non-standard location, you should add a rule in file labeling database. This avoids problems the next time file system is relabeled or `restorecon` is used. Choose the label [appropriately](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux) or use the already applied label (check the existing security labels with `ls -lZ`).

Adding a labeling rule for `/path/to/directory` and its contents using [`semanage`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html):

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_rw_content_t '/path/to/directory(/.*)?'
```

If your files are on different file system, you can use [*`context` option*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Mounting_File_Systems.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Mounting_File_Systems-Context_Mounts) for the mount point to apply/override the default labeling.

Comment: What is "path to working file" in this context?

Comment: You don't have any php files which work with apache? What does `audit2why` tell you?

Comment: I do but which one of the "working files" should I choose?

Comment: They likely have the same labels (check with `ls -lZ`), so any (working php file) will do.